# Check if expression returns string in bash in until condition

Tags: bash, expression, conditional-statements

I need a script to wait until an expression, `$instance_id`, returns a string value before continuing.

I've tried multiple conditions and can't get it to work. Is this an evaluation issue? e.g. Does `$instance_id` evaluate only one in the until condition? At the end of my rope. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# get instance id, strip quotes from string
request_id=$(cat $log_file | jq '.SpotInstanceRequests[0] .SpotInstanceRequestId')
printf "\rRequest $request_id submitted."

function get_request_state {
    aws ec2 describe-spot-instance-requests \
            --filters Name=spot-instance-request-id,Values=[$request_id]
}

function get_instance_id {
    echo $(get_request_state) | \
    jq '.SpotInstanceRequests[0] .InstanceId' | \
    sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'
}

# check if instance created every 3s
# TODO: Stop script if request is terminated
spin="/-\|"
instance_id=''
while [ -z $instance_id ] || [ "$instance_id"=="null" ]; do
    # run spinner
    for i in `seq 1 30`; do
        j=$(( (j+1) %4 ))
        printf "\rWaiting for request to be fulfilled...${spin:$j:1}"
        sleep .1
    done
    instance_id=$(get_instance_id)
done
printf "Request fulfilled.\nInstance id:\t$instance_id"
```

*Updated with suggestions from comments, answers. Still stuck in infinite loop.

Comment: Isn't the logic of the test condition flipped? "until [ -z $instance_id ]" means "do this for as long as $instance_id contains something". Also, as the spin loop does not update $instance_id, I guess it's an infinite loop.

Comment: `[ "$foo"=="null" ]` is a condition that will **always** be true, because it checks if the result of appending the string `==null` to the contents of your variable `foo` is a non-empty string, which it always is.

Comment: You need more spaces: `[ "$foo" = null ]`, for example, does what you intend.

Comment: ...and btw, better to use native-bash math: `for ((i=0; i<30; i++)); do`, for example, vs depending on the unspecified not-part-of-POSIX not-part-of-bash external command `seq`.

Comment: And `echo $(get_request_state) | ...` is silly -- it just adds inefficiency and bugs compared to `get_request_state | ...` (the bugs being caused by the unquoted expansion; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)).

Comment: And if you don't want quotes in `jq` output, use the `-r` argument; there's no need to take them off with `sed`.

Comment: It's also better practice to `printf '\r%s' "$foo"` than `printf "\r$foo"`, since it ensures that content taken from your variable is treated as literal, not as a format string.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I think what I really needed to know was that command substitutes are evaluated only once. Thus, the one I originally used to get `$instance_id` was never being updated in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to a faulty conditional (I think you want a `while`), you are checking outside of the loop, so the request is only made before the loop, never (or in this case always) satisfying the condition.

Comment: I think you're right, but I'm still not sure what the solution is. I've tried a few different things with your suggestions (see edit above for example), but I get stuck in an infinite loop now. Any thoughts?

Comment: ```while [ -z $instance_id ] || [ $instance_id = null ]; do     for i in `seq 1 30`; do         j=$(( (j+1) %4 ));         printf "\rWaiting for request to be fulfilled...${spin:$j:1}";         sleep .1;     done; instance_id=$(your_func); done``` works for me, so if that still doesn't work, check your `aws-cli` call.